# 2D bash arrays: is this possible?

Tags: bash, array

If I want a 2D bash array, is there any recommended way of doing this for say, a `N x M` arrangement? On several occasions, I've had to define `array1`, `array2`, `arrayN` each of `M` elements in conjunction with case statements - but this is very clumsy.

I realise it would be possible to define a single big array `X` and compute a 1-1 map between `X[something]` and the `[i,j]` element - but this seems like a lot of work to do it properly.

Does there exist any set of functions which could do this reasonably efficiently?
I realise its a bit like making Bash imitate FORTRAN.

Comment: You can do the same thing awk does: emulate multi-dim arrays with single-dim *associative* arrays. Eg. `declare -A a; i=2; j=3; a[$i,$j]=4; echo ${a[2,3]}`. Of course, nicely iterating through rows and cols will be a bitch. But if you need to handle complex data structures, using bash is certainly not the best idea.

Comment: Or emulate them with indexed arrays: `declare -a a; i=2; j=3; a[i<<16|j]=4; echo ${a[2<<16|3]}` (assuming that 65536 x 65536 is enough for everybody ;-)).

Comment: Indexed arrays seem to be very simple and fast. The only question is why aren't they built into Bash since they are "simple & fast" - I presume they are built on sparse arrays?

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, the indexed arrays in bash are sparse; `a[1<<30]=foo` will NOT allocate 1G of empty slots. And like everything in bash, they're also very slow ;-)

Comment: The shell is not the type of language you usually want to use for things requiring multi-dimensional arrays. It may be more efficient to move to some other scripting language, such as Python, Perl, or any common compiled language.

Comment: Very true, but occasionally you just want to amend a bash script to do something it wasn't originally meant to do. Avoids a total rewrite and quite often speed is not an issue.

Comment: @JeremyBoden If speed is not an issue, then why not just emulate a multi-dimensional array in a 1-dimensional array with `a(i,j) == a[i*ncols + j]` or similar transformation?  This is a common way to do it when managing 1D structures is easier (or more efficient) than managing multi-D structures.

Answer (score 3):

You could always switch to `ksh93` (whose syntax `bash` has borrowed in the first place for most things) which has multidimensional arrays.

```
var=(
  (a b)
  (c d)
)
```

Use as:

```
$ print -r -- "${var[0][1]}"
b
```

To loop over all the elements:

```
for i in "${!var[@]}"; do
  for j in "${!var[$i][@]}"; do
    print -r "var[$i,$j]=${var[$i][$j]}"
  done
done
```

Comment: If anybody has to fight the bash shell, it's because it's supposedly present scarequotes-"everywhere". If one has the luxury to switch to ksh93, they could also switch to APL or J ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can emulate multidimensional arrays with one-dimensional associative arrays (the way awk does it [1]), or with indexed arrays, by shifting the index.

The problem is that you cannot iterate through them in an obvious, natural way.

```
declare -A a  # associative array
i=2; j=3; a[$i,$j]=4; echo ${a[2,3]}

unset a
declare -a a  # indexed array, the default
i=2; j=3; a[i<<16|j]=4; echo ${a[2<<16|3]}
```

Notice that the *indexed* arrays in bash are *sparse*; `a[1<<30]=1` will NOT create `1Gi - 1` empty slots, neither in actual RAM, nor in the virtual address space. Also, since bash's indexed arrays are implemented as *doubly-linked lists*, random access to an element is *slower* than with associative arrays (which are using the same hash table implementation bash is using for caching the paths of external commands).

[1] Awk automatically turns an expression like `a[x,y,z]` into `a[x SUBSEP y SUBSEP z]` -- where the default value of `SUBSEP` is `\x1c` (`^\`), a control character not supposed to appear in keys. GNU awk also has real multidimensional arrays as a non-standard extension. The classical awk multi-dim array emulation is also available in perl (`$;` => `SUBSEP`).